# How to view a TTF font file?

Tags: fonts, ttf

Is there an application to simply preview a font from a TTF file without installing it?

Answer (score 109):

I use character maps heavily and decides to make one which you access from anywhere using [a web interface](http://mathew-kurian.github.io/CharacterMap/) and requires no installation. Works best on Chrome.

Features

- Select your own font file
- Provides font and character information
- Character copy-able
- Supports TTF/OTF
- Supports Icon fonts
- Simple interface
- No installation necessary
- No server upload necessary

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Very nice. But I can't see how to navigate through the characters. It shows ranges of 200 chars, but clicking on those ranges doesn't do anything, so only the first 200 chars are ever visible.

Comment: It seems the version on that link has a bug. Running the version from https://github.com/bluejamesbond/CharacterMap/ locally works (needs node and npm)

Comment: http://opentype.js.org/

Comment: I get an error "TypeError: glyph is undefined" when trying to upload "Noto Color Emoji" font (https://www.google.com/get/noto/#emoji-zsye-color)

Comment: Nice tool, would have been great if we could search from the unicode

Comment: Look like this heroku project is now dead (?)

Answer (score 38):

`gnome-font-viewer` (part of GNOME of course) can do this (this is the default association for fonts under GNOME); indeed, it comes with a button to install the font, which obviously wouldn't make sense if the font needed to be installed already.

[fontmatrix](https://github.com/fontmatrix/fontmatrix) lets you organize groups of fonts to be installed or uninstalled, and you can preview them and see their features, whether installed or not.

Most font editors, like [fontforge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net), certainly don't require the fonts to be installed to open them up and look at them...

There are others, I'm sure.

Comment: not installed by default in all ubuntu variations. thanks.

Answer (score 30):

```
display OpenSans-CondBold.ttf
```

[image: what <code>display</code> displays when opening a font file]

`display` is part of `imagemagick`, so you will need it to be installed.

Answer possible thanks to [this forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=923075#p923075).

This problem has been bugging me for years, because it is only every few months that I want to preview a font and I never remembered which software solved it last time, so I made a [video version of this answer](http://youtu.be/HR6TP5rmb4k) to make it easier to find in the future.

Comment: Related: [imagemagick display: different text in font preview - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70742/imagemagick-display-different-text-in-font-preview)

Answer (score 14):

[Font Manager](http://code.google.com/p/font-manager/) is very handy for previewing and comparing fonts. It allows you to install TTF files, even if zipped, and will preview them pretty quickly. It does install them in your `~/.fonts` directory, but it's pretty easy to remove them.

[image: Font Manager]

Answer (score 5):

[GNOME Characters](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-characters)

> Characters is a simple utility application to find and insert unusual characters.

Requires font installation but displays emojis for me where gnome-font-viewer fails. Install through snap or compile.

```
sudo snap install gnome-characters
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[Glyphr Studio Online](http://www.glyphrstudio.com/online/) is an online, free, web based font designer. As character maps, you can view the font, but also edit.

[image: Glyphr Studio Online]

Answer (score 0):

[fontpreview](https://github.com/MatteoGuadrini/fontpreview#command-line-interface) with command line interface:

```
fp /tmp/noto.ttf
```

This command also other functionality, like color, size and position:

```
fp /tmp/noto.ttf -b 'green' -f 'blue' -p 'lcenter' -z 50
```