# imagemagick display: different text in font preview

Tags: fonts, imagemagick

The awesome `display` command from imagemagick allows me to preview fonts:

```
display ~/.fonts/font.ttf
```

However, the text is always the same ('That which does not destroy me, only makes me stronger'). Is there a way to change the standard text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to alter the source code (more specifically the [TTF coder](https://github.com/trevor/ImageMagick/blob/master/coders/ttf.c), line 276) and recompile IM if you want to have a different text sample in font preview.

Answer (score 1):

There is a script for ImageMagick tools to show fonts with several bells & whistles
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/scripts/show_fonts.

Answer (score 0):

(summary from the script listed in the [other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278757/296692))

Use the command:

```
convert -font /path/to/file.ttf -pointsize 200 label:"text" out.png && display out.png
```

`text` is the text to be displayed. `200` is the font size used in the example.

For some reason, `display` (or `magick display`) [doesn't recognize the `-pointsize` option](https://imagemagick.org/script/display.php) (while [`convert` does](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php)), so I have to store it to a temporary file then display it. (`out.png` in this example, but can be anything)

Unfortunately, this method doesn't allow you to easily show the font at different sizes like the preview.

Alternatively use `display` directly:

```
display -density 400 -font file.ttf label:"text"
```